# Sort large CSV file by specific column using csvhelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a big csv file contains about 20 millions records (size 4GB)

My goal is to read data from this file and sort the list by specific columns (multi columns, not one column) in that csv file. I'm currently using [csvhelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) library to achieve my goal
My idea is to add data to a List so I can use Linq function to order the data as expect

When using `csvReader.GetRecords<T>()`, it returns an `IQueryable<T>` data. but when adding `.ToList()` then it throws a `System.OutOfMemoryException`

```cs
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<T>();
```

I tried another way to add it to list by calling a for loop and add it to an empty `List<T>`

```cs
List<T> lst = new List<T>();
foreach (var item in datas)
{
  lst.Add(item);
}
```

but it still throws `System.OutOfMemoryException`

is there any solution to add data from csv file to List and order my list by specific columns
My PC has 16GB RAM and the file has about 4GB size

Comment: Are you compiling to 64bit or 32bits?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: I'm using .net framework 4.6.1, comple using 64bit @mag

Comment: That is a lot of data to manage all at once let alone make in memory copies of.  I'd chop it into smaller files which could then be loaded into a database, perhaps SQLite.  Then a consumable CSV could be exported in whatever order is desired.

Comment: You may try setting [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element)

Comment: Besides why do you think you need to call ToList first to use Linq? It should be possible to use Linq directly. records should be an IEnumerable<T>. ToList will copy things around needing additional memory you are obviously short off.

Comment: @Ralf i'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: It should be possible to simply call `records.OrderBy(myFirstSortCondition).ThenBy(myOtherSortCondition)` etc. No need to call ToList before that and needing extra memory.

Comment: I know your idea about calling linq functions directly. I'm asking about gcAllowVeryLargeObjects

Comment: Then i don't know whast to tell you here. I linked the documentation its all in there.

Comment: If you wait a little, I will attach general Merge Sort solution through enumerable (in memory or in file).

Comment: You could write the data to an SQL table and use MySQL (other engines are available) to do the sorting and, indeed, anything else you want to do with it. Database engines are optimised for dealing with large datasets. It depends on what you mean by 'large'.

Comment: See my answer. May contain errors, because wrote in hurry, so any comments appreciated.

Comment: check and see if this helps! https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1185848/Cinchoo-ETL-Sorting-Large-CSV-File

Comment: Using SQLite like @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp suggested is a good idea. You could also use Lucene.net and do the indexing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Chop it into subsets, sort, then merge. Here is code example of extension I wrote:

```
public static class MergeSortEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TElement> MergeOrderBy<TElement, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TElement> sourceEnumerable, Func<TElement, TKey> keyProvider,
        IEnumerableStorage<TElement> storage, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null, int minimalChunkSize = 1024*1024)
    {
        if(sourceEnumerable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sourceEnumerable));
        if (storage == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(storage));
        if (keyProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keyProvider));

        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        storage.Clear();
        //chunking, sorting, saving
        foreach (var chunk in sourceEnumerable.ChunkInPlace(minimalChunkSize))
        {
            chunk.Sort((x,y)=> comparer.Compare(keyProvider(x), keyProvider(y)));
            storage.Add(chunk);
        }

        if (storage.Count == 0)
            return Enumerable.Empty<TElement>();

        //making a merge tree IEnumerable out of all files, it will cost us O(totalSize/chunkSize) open handles
        var queue = new Queue<IEnumerable<TElement>>(storage.Count);
        while (storage.Count > 0)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(storage.Take());
        }
        while (queue.Count > 1)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(MergeSorted(queue.Dequeue(), queue.Dequeue(), keyProvider, comparer));
        }
        return queue.Dequeue();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TElement> MergeSorted<TElement, TKey>(IEnumerable<TElement> a, IEnumerable<TElement> b, Func<TElement, TKey> keyProvider, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        using var aiter = a.GetEnumerator();
        using var biter = b.GetEnumerator();

        var amoved = aiter.MoveNext();
        var bmoved = biter.MoveNext();
        while (amoved || bmoved)
        {
            var cmp = amoved && bmoved ? comparer.Compare(keyProvider(aiter.Current), keyProvider(biter.Current)) : (amoved ? -1 : 1);
            if (cmp <= 0)
            {
                yield return aiter.Current;
                amoved = aiter.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return biter.Current;
                bmoved = biter.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }

    //chop incoming enumerable into chunks, but uses same array each time to lower GC usage
    private static IEnumerable<List<TValue>> ChunkInPlace<TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> values,
        int chunkSize)
    {
        var list = new List<TValue>(chunkSize);
        using var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            list.Add(enumerator.Current);
            if (list.Count == chunkSize)
            {
                yield return list;
                list.Clear();
            }
        }

        if (list.Count > 0)
            yield return list;
        list.Clear();
    }
}
```

You basically write a streamed version of persistent storage (in `CSV`/`Json` any other format, or just straight into `SQL`) with `Push`/`Pop` methods and plug it into extension.
Memory tradeoff/consumption can be adjusted selecting minimal size - depends on size and amount of entities you want to sort at a time. This way you can sort any amount of data, even if it is not reside on your disk. It can easily be cloud blob storage.

**Usage**

```
var sorted = infiniteInput.MergeOrderBy(x=> x.DickSize, tmpStorage); //you can safely use it in foreach or any other memory cheap extension like Any(), First(), Last(), Sum(), etc
```

**Benchmark in memory 1 million ints**

```
|          Method |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev | Completed Work Items | Lock Contentions | Allocated |
|---------------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|---------------------:|-----------------:|----------:|
| MergeSortOnDisk | 285.6 ms | 5.67 ms | 7.76 ms |               1.0000 |                - |   12.2 MB |
```

**Benchmark in json 1 million ints**

```
|          Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Completed Work Items | Lock Contentions | Allocated |
|---------------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|---------------------:|-----------------:|----------:|
| MergeSortOnDisk | 1.545 s | 0.0301 s | 0.0282 s |               2.0000 |                - | 314.26 MB |
```

**PS**

Link at my repo with tests/benchmarks (and storage examples):

https://github.com/eocron/Algorithm/tree/master/Algorithm/Sorted

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded 20 million records of a simple `Foo` class of `Id` and `Name`.  The file was 0.4 GB, but the loaded records in memory was close to 2GB. If we assume your class is also going to need about 5 times the memory, then you would need 20GB memory for your 4GB file.  Even if you do manage to load all the records, you are going to need more memory to do the sorting.

If you don't want to use the suggestion from [Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213376/sort-large-csv-file-by-specific-column-using-csvhelper#comment132722427_75213376) to upload the file to a database, you might be able to use a smaller `SortingClass` that only has the columns that you want to sort on and a `Row` column that will allow you to find the records again in the file. After sorting, if you just need a smaller subset of the records, use the row numbers to find the complete records in the file.

```cs
void Main()
{
    List<SortingClass> sortedRecords;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\VeryLargeFoo.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<SortingClassMap>();
        sortedRecords = csv.GetRecords<SortingClass>().OrderByDescending(f => f.Name).ThenBy(f => f.Id).ToList();
    }
    
    var selectedRows = sortedRecords.Take(100).Select(r => r.Row).ToArray();
    var selectedFoo = new List<Foo>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\VeryLargeFoo.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            if (selectedRows.Contains(csv.Parser.Row)){
                selectedFoo.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SortingClass
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SortingClassMap : ClassMap<SortingClass>
{
    public SortingClassMap()
    {
        Map(r => r.Row).Convert(args => args.Row.Context.Parser.Row);
        Map(r => r.Id);
        Map(r => r.Name);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public string Column4 { get; set; }
    public string Column5 { get; set; }
    public string Column6 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i tried to use the code above, `sortedRecords = csv.GetRecords<SortingClass>().OrderByDescending(f => f.Name).ThenBy(f => f.Id).ToList();`', it throws exception mentioned in the first post. I'm not sure your code runs expectly

Comment: the call `GetRecords` returns 20 millions records and `ToList` method throws exception. remove `ToList` will run expectedly

Comment: I believe any access to the records will have to pull them all into memory, where you'll see the exception.

Comment: I just tried adding 10 more columns to the `Foo` class and I made a file that was 5GB with 20 million records.  When I tried pulling in all the `Foo` records, my memory usage for LINQPad jumped to 18.7GB.  If I only pulled the 3 columns with `SortingClass`, my memory usage was 2.8GB.  It is possible that the columns @Ming-Hieu is sorting on have a lot of data and are still large enough to cause the `System.OutOfMemoryException`, but this should work to considerably limit the memory used.

Comment: @DavidSpecht my csv file has 16 columns and my goal is only to sort by 2 columns. So are there any solutions if I have to pull all columns and sort by 2 columns by default?

Comment: @JoshClose I only access the records once when calling `records.OrderBy().ThenBy()`. I don't think the memory will be overflow

Comment: The ordering and the sorting don't happen until it's projected through something like `ToList`. All of the data has to be in memory to sort and order.

Comment: @JoshClose nope, it can be on disk, then merged. See my solution, its just uses temorary files to offload sorted data on disk, then merges them. If storage correctly enumerate entities then it will be O(total_size/chunk_size) in RAM and O(n*log(n)) at speed. You can sort terrabytes of data.

Comment: @eocron In your solution, yes.